# Gitlab-runner: docker or docker-compose not found in root but they already installed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've already installed gitlab runner and docker and docker-compose via Sudo in CentOS 7/Ubuntu OS and all pipelines work well but when I active another project to the gitlab-runner then it doesn't recognize anything such as sudo. and also sometimes the current runner acts like the new gitlab project results, docker or docker-compose and I don't know why?

```sh
$ whoami
root
$ docker info
/bin/sh: eval: line 59: docker: not found
```

OR

```sh
$ docker-compose --version
/bin/sh: eval: line 59: docker-compose: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is we should **disable** the **shared runners** because docker and docker-compose or other things is not installed into shared runners. so after disabling them, everything will work correctly as well as desired.

> The shared runners have disabled in following image:

[image]